# C# EntityFramework Include reference and its references, how?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I am using .NET Core 2.0

I do have 3 models:

```
class ModelA {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<ModelB> Emails { get; set; }
}

class ModelB {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public ModelA Request { get; set; }
    public List<ModelC> Tokens { get; set; }
}

class ModelC {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public string getStatusName()
    {
        string[] Statuses = new string[] {
            "Created",      // 0
            "Approved",     // 1
            "Rejected"      // 2
        };

        return Statuses[Status];
    }
}
```

I do also have context created like this:

```
public class RequestorContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ModelA> Request { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModelB> Email { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModelC> Token { get; set; }

    public RequestorContext(DbContextOptions<RequestorContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Now I would like to do such thing in controller:

```
var request = await _context.Request
                .Include(r => r.Emails) //also include tokens - how ???
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id);
```

**So basically how to include corresponding tokens to emails?**
To be able to do such thing in the view:

```
@foreach (var email in Model.Emails)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@email.Name</td>
        <td>@email.Token.Token</td>
        <td>@email.Token.getStatusName()</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Currently I am getting error like this:

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null
>   reference CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , object )
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0)
>   AspNetCore._Views_Requestor_Details_cshtml+d__8.MoveNext()
>   in Details.cshtml
>   +
>                       @email.Token.getStatusName()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load multiple levels of related data use `ThenInclude` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels).

To solve your issue your code would look like this:

```
var request = await _context.Request
            .Include(r => r.Emails)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Tokens)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id);
```